# Save position of element with Jquery, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

On the whole, I want to save position of the element, when it has dropped (for example, it's a link) :

```
<a class="icon" style="left:20px;top:20px;" href="some_href">
      <img src="some_src" />
      name
</a>
```

Elements with this class are draggable. I think,that here must be ajax, but how to do this correctly - don't know.
I am a php - mysql programmer, and so noob in jQuery and JS :(
Thank for all answers and sorry for my bad English! :)

Comment: -1 [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do mean by *"saving position of an element"* and how can that be useful, but you can try jQuery [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

```
var t = $('a.icon').position().top;
var l = $('a.icon').position().left;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  data: { top: t, left: l}
}).done(function() {
  alert( "Position Saved");
});
```